# Mobilesubstrate tweak not loading

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia-substrate

I am trying to make simple tweak with iOSOpenDev Captain-Hook tweak. Here is my code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CaptainHook/CaptainHook.h"

CHDeclareClass(TESTCLASS); // declare class

CHOptimizedMethod(0, self, void, TESTCLASS, testm) // hook method (with no arguments and no return value)
{
    // write code here ...
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"HACK" message:@"message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    //CHSuper(0, TESTCLASS, testm); // call old (original) method
    //return nil;
}

CHConstructor // code block that runs immediately upon load
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        CHLoadLateClass(TESTCLASS);  // load class (that will be "available later")
        CHHook(0, TESTCLASS, testm); // register hook
    }
}
```

Also I have plist with filtered bundle of my other app.
My other app calls `[TESTCLASS testm]`. And if I place .plist and .dylib in /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries it not works, nothing happens. But if I add dylib to project in my second app and compile it, it works, even without copying actual dylib to the app(uses that in /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries) and shows my alert.
How can I make it work?

Tried with hooking some example calls for springboard - they not work.
Using Xcode 5.0.2, iOSOpenDev 1.6-2, iPad1 5.1.1

Comment: So the new evasi0n jailbreak has been released...

Comment: Did you find out what is the problem?

Comment: Seems something related to project building for Captain Hook template. I created new project with template Logos tweak but pasted code and files from Captain hook tweak and now it works. Still don't figured out why Captain Hook's template is not work.

Comment: CHOptimizedMethod is not used properly.